# Are there any online services available to exchange prepaid cards into BTC?

Tags: exchanges, usa, localbitcoins, trucoin

I live in the USA.
I would like to use prepaid cards to buy some BTC (less than $100USD)
I've tried trucoin.com and the wait time is enormous, 4 days since sign up and still haven't received an invite.

I've also tried circle.com but they do not currently accept prepaid options.

What other options does a prepaid card user have?

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a Target or Walmart gift card and trade it for Bitcoin in https://cardforcoin.com/

Answer (score 0):

I like them: https://cryptopay.me/ and recommend them, had never any troubles with them.

*There are several not recommended, please make your own research*

Answer (score -1):

Besides using something like http://localbitcoins.com, you can try https://purse.io/ and buy stuff for people on amazon with your card and get bitcoins back.